# Tree method with 8T(n/2) +n^2

Tags: math, tree, big-o

I'm trying to solve this problem, but I think I haven't understood how to do it correctly. The first thing I do in this type of exercises is taking the bigger value in the row (in this case is n^2) and divide it multiple times, so I can find what kind of relation there is between the values. After found the relation, I try to mathematically found its value and then as the final step, I multiply the result for the root. In this case the result should be n^3. How is possible?
[image]

Comment: It is not really clear what are you trying to do, but if my guess is right, you probably should (re-)read the [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) which answers most of the questions of this kind.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to solve it with the tree method

Comment: It doesn't really need to be a tree since there is only one recursive call - the tree method is only useful for multiple different calls. But in case you *have to* use it, you have the wrong number of branches - it should be 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately @vahidreza's solutions seems false to me because it contradicts the Master theorem. In terms of the Master theorem `a = 8`, `b = 2`, `c = 2`. So `log_b(a) = 3` so `log_b(a) > c` and thus this is the case of a recursion dominated by the subproblems so the answer should be `T(n) = Ө(n^3)` rather than `O(m^(2+1/3))` which @vahidreza has.

The main issue is probably in this statement:

> Also you know that the tree has log_8 m levels. Because at each level, you divide the number by 8.

Let's try to solve it properly:

- On the zeroth level you have `n^2` (I prefer to start counting from `0` as it simplifies notation a bit)
- on the first level you have `8` nodes of `(n/2)^2` or a total of `8*(n/2)^2`
- on the second level you have `8 * 8` nodes of `(n/(2^2))^2` or a total of `8^2*(n/(2^2))^2`
- on the `i`-th level you have `8^i` nodes of `(n/(2^i))^2` or a total of `8^i*(n/(2^i))^2` = `n^2 * 8^i/2^(2*i)` = `n^2 * 2^i`

At each level your value `n` is divided by two so at level `i` the value is `n/2^i` and so you'll have `log_2(n)` levels. So what you need to calculate is sum for `i` from `0` to `log_2(n)` of `n^2 * 2^i`. That's a geometric progression with a ratio of `2` so it's sum is

```
Σ (n^2 * 2^i) = n^2 * Σ(2^i) = n^2 * (2^(log_2(n)+1) - 1)/2
```

Since we are talking about `Ө`/`O` we can ignore constants and so we need to estimate

```
n^2 * 2^log_2(n)
```

Obviously `2^log_2(n)` is just `n` so the answer is

```
T(n) = Ө(n^3)
```

exactly as predicted by the Master theorem.

Comment: You are right. I made a dire mistake. I deleted my answer. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved my problem! Just one more question: in this example I divide for two in each level because I have T(n/2), but what about if I have T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/3) + n? Here I'm dividing my tree into two branches with two different values